# Selenium and C# Text Box without a name or ID

Tags: c#, selenium, search, textbox, uisearchbar

I Have a search text box with out a name.

How should this code change to handle it?

```
 IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("searchBoxText"));
```

Comment: so do you have anything that could identify that box??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Got it thanks..  I am new to StackOverflow and learning how things work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to grab it by xpath but that will be fragile.

```
IWebElement result = Browser.instance.FindElement(By.XPath("INSERT PATH HERE"));
```